# Where does MVC do it's URL/Route pattern matching?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Does anyone know the class(s) and method(s) within the Microsoft MVC framwork (any version, 3,4,5 etc) that actually does the pattern matching exercise on the URL to establish which route to use?

I'm interested to look at the actual mechanics of URL parsing but can't find the code using ILSpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look under `System.Web.Mvc.Routing`. Specifically, `RouteBuilder` may contain what you're looking for.

Here's the [source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Routing/RouteBuilder.cs).